# d3 div doesn't change size on attribute changes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

I have a pie chart in my angular application. The pie chart is a pie and a legend. For some reason I can't change the width and height of my div's in d3 whenever I select my legend. I can change the width and height of my svg element without any problem however.

[image: inspect]

---

[image: legend]

Here is the code that I currently have:

```
  buildSvg() {
    this.host.html('').attr('class', 'host');

    this.svg = d3
      .select('.host')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', this.size[0])
      .attr('height', this.size[1])
      .attr('class', 'pie-chart')
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(${this.size[0] / 2},${this.size[1] / 2})`)
      .attr('class', 'pie-content');

    this.legend = d3
      .select('.host')
      .append('div')
      .attr('class', 'legend');

    d3.select('.legend')
      .attr('width', this.size[0])
      .attr('height', this.size[1]);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Svg and html have subtle differences. You cannot assign width/height to a div in the same way you can to an svg. Best approach is setting `style` attribute with appropriate CSS formatting; see below for an example

```css
div.a {
 background-color: red;
}

div.b {
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="a" width="100" height="100">width="100" height="100"</div>
<div class="b" style="width: 100px; height: 100px">style="width: 100px; height: 100px"</div>
```

Comment: d3.select('.legend').style('width', '100px'); did the trick! Thank you very much!

Comment: A quick follow up question: I try to display the content in my host by adding a       .style('display', 'inline-block' to my host,, so my items will display in a horizontal order. This doesnt seem to work however. Is there any other issues with trying to display elements of div's and svg's horizontally together with my method above?